# Did we bork our repository? -- merged wrong way, then reverted, now merging the other way does something weird

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-revert

- We have Dev, our long term release branch (not Master, don't ask why)
- We also have FeatureBranch, an old branch with many commits/pushes
- I mistakenly merged Dev to FeatureBranch rather than the other way, so Dev commits were applied to FeatureBranch (d5de75c)
- I did this using SourceTree; conflicts arose; I resolved them
- We reverted FeatureBranch to the commit before the bad merge
- We then merged FeatureBranch to Dev, this time via pull request from Bitbucket (78e4c0f)
- No conflicts arose this time!
- **This operation appeared to undo commits that were on Dev**
- **Is this because revert commits are now on FeatureBranch?**
- We have reverted the merge (ae2bf73)

**What's the best way to merge FeatureBranch to Dev now?** I'm tempted to force push to FeatureBranch from before the debauchery began, then try merging again, hoping for different behavior. We are a small team with very few local changes, so we can adapt fairly easy to an altered origin history, but still, I'd like to avoid a force push if possible.

git log; I'm locally reset to f0e83d1:

```
 *   ae2bf73 (origin/Dev, Dev) Merged in undo22 (pull request #23)
 |\  
 | * d0292f4 (origin/undo22) Revert "Merge FeatureBranch to Dev (pull request #22)"
 |/  
 *   78e4c0f Merged in FeatureBranch (pull request #22)
 |\  
 | * 3c2f132 (origin/FeatureBranch) Re-adding accidentally reverted change.
 | * f586c2e Revert "Merge branch 'Dev' into FeatureBranch"
 | * e996bcc Revert "#IC-67 #IC-179 [Redacted]"
 | *   d5de75c Merge branch 'Dev' into FeatureBranch
 | |\  
 | * | f0e83d1 (HEAD -> FeatureBranch) #IC-67 #IC-179 [Redacted]
```

Comment: If by "reverted FeatureBranch", you mean "made commits that updated the state of the working tree to what it was before the merge", possibly by using the `git revert` command, then yes, those changes are going to persist. If you don't want those changes, you'll probably need to reset the branches to reference revisions before those commits were made.

Comment: I think you have to revert a revert somewhere, but it's a bit complex to kinda "picture in my mind".  Could you get a graph display for this (and you can redact it to your hearts' content)?  Use `git log --graph --pretty="%h %d" --decorate --all` to get some output we could poke at.  If you're OK with commit messages popping up you could use `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`.

Comment: @Makoto - Thanks, I have added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) creates a new commit, which essentially erases changes that came before it.

When you created a revert commit on `FeatureBranch`, it became a new commit that essentially erased the changes on `Dev`. You then merged that commit into `Dev`.

However... not all is lost.

In this kind of extreme scenario, sometimes the best course of action is to do something that's a bit **insane**: [Rewrite History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). Please note that this should be undertaken with some caution, so read up before committing to this course of action. (No pun intended.)

1. Checkout your `Dev` branch.
2. Look at your commit history.
3. Write down the current HEAD hash id for your `Dev` branch. You may need it in case things go sideways.
4. Now find the last commit before the shenanigans began, then locally run [`git reset --hard COMMIT_HASH_ID`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) (replacing "COMMIT_HASH_ID" with the commit id, e.g. `3daee367b`). This is like a revert, except that instead of creating a new commit which erases prior changes, it rolls back as if the changes had never happened.
5. Now run [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force-with-leaseltrefnamegt). You might need to reconfigure BitBucket to let you do this, although it sounds like you haven't protected `Dev` (which is likely why you are in this trouble in the first place).

   *Note that this will cause a **significant disruption** for anyone else who has checked out `Dev` with these recent commits. They may also need to run `git reset --hard COMMIT_HASH_ID` for their local Dev branches to get back on track. (They will not need to `push`, though.)*

   [image]

(You can repeat these steps for `FeatureBranch` if you need to.)

Now got to BitBucket and [**protect your `Dev` branch**](https://bitbucket.org/blog/take-control-with-branch-restrictions) to prevent these kinds of accidents in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Did you notice that we reverted the merge to Dev? We think Dev is in good shape now, we just need to start over with the merge of the (now wonkified) FeatureBranch branch.

Comment: @MackTuesday - I think `git reset` will get you back where you want to be. It'll erase all the nonsense as if nothing ever happened. Just keep track of the current commit hash. If anything goes wrong, you can run `get checkout OLD_HASH` and see all of your prior history/changes and restore anything you need.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be possible to merge `FeatureBranch` as it is into `dev`, because `dev` already have all the commits as part of it. (even if another commit basically undid everything done on `FeatureBranch`)

While resetting as written in [the answer given by JDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668599/1978365) might be a solution, there is also a way which is less disruptive to other developers.

1. Find the point were you feature branch originally split from dev and take the hash.
2. Run `git rebase TheHash -f` see [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--f)

The above will copy all commits into a new branch. Since none of the new commits are part of the history of `dev` you can do a normal merge.